# Shiny widgets or packages to easily and visually modify the elements and order of elements in a vector?

Tags: r, vector, shiny, visualization

What are the options out there for readily, and preferably visually, modifying (adding, deleting, re-ordering) elements in a vector?

Explanation:

In an App I'm building, numeric input X needs to be allocated along a specified sequence of priorities. This sequence of priorities and related data will be stored in a vector or similar object. Example of priorities:

1. 100% of X goes to cover a calculated amount needed for A (call it
   "class A"),
2. 100% of any X remaining after covering class A (X-A) goes to cover a calculated amount needed for class B,
3. 100% of any X remaining after covering A and B (X-A-B) goes to cover any past
   shortfalls in class B,
4. 100% of any X remaining after covering the
   preceding (X-A-B-B) is split 50/50 between amounts calculated for
   classes C1 and a C2, respectively
5. 100% of any X remaining after covering all of the preceding (X-A-B-(C1 and C2)) is accumulated in D.

The user will specify the classes (A/B/C...), introduce labels, specify the percentages, and will need to be able to subsequently modify those orderings. There should be no theoretical limit on the number of classes introduced (but in reality there will usually be 4 to 12).

Is there an R/Shiny functionality or package that allows a user to do this sort of ordering, this prioritisation, visually? Or some sort of flowcharting that results in numeric prioritisations? Or something somewhat close or similar?

Ideally, a user would be visually presented only with a box "A" upon invoking the App (basically by default assuming the residual accumulation function described for Class D in item 5 above). Following the above example of priorities: the user would right-click on the A box and split it into boxes A and B, with A positioned above the B to show the order of priority. The user enters labels into A and B and their respective allocation percentages. The user then clicks on B and inserts C below it. The user right-clicks on C and selects the option to split it into 2 components of C1 and C2. And so and so forth. Basically you end up with a flowchart or something like a flowchart, and the positions of the boxes in that flowchart/similar tell the code how to allocate the stream of X (a "waterfall" so to speak).

The above may be fantasy. But I wonder what's out there for easy user inputs for vector prioritisation and subsequent modifications.

Building this from scratch would be a monstrous undertaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `rank_list` from library([sortable](https://rstudio.github.io/sortable/)):

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = "classNames", label = "Classes", choices = "A", selected="A",
                 multiple = TRUE, options = list(
                   'plugins' = list('remove_button'),
                   'create' = TRUE,
                   'persist' = FALSE)
  ),
  uiOutput("rank_listUI"),
  textOutput("classesOrder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rank_listUI <- renderUI({
    rank_list(
      text = "Order classes",
      labels = input$classNames,
      input_id = "sortableClasses"
    )}
  )
  
  output$classesOrder <- renderText({paste("Current order:", paste0(input$sortableClasses, collapse = ", "))})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Currently I'm not aware of any library allowing the scenario you describe in the second part of your question. The only thing that comes close is library([d3Tree](https://github.com/yonicd/d3Tree)), which is aiming at interactively displaying hierarchical data.